# В Linux Debian  нет стандартно программы make. Как устанавливать?

Tags: makefile, debian, linux

Установил Linux Debian. Все стандартные программы есть, а хочу установить pindgin и ещё парочку. А там надо из исходников собирать. А там нужен make. Ввел в терминале
make
Вывел
bash: make: команда не найдена.
Скачал этот make с офф. сайта. Глянул файл INSTALL и README. Ничего не понял. 
Как установить этот make? Напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы под рутом pidgin пытались собрать?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если есть необходимость компилировать софт, то одного make может быть мало. Поэтому обычно более оптимальным является установка пакета build-essential, который содержит make в том числе. В убунте он поставит к примеру dpkg-dev (package building tools for Debian
g++ (The GNU C++ compiler), gcc (The GNU C compiler), libc6-dev (GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files) or libc-dev (virtual package provided by libc6-dev) и
make.
В Debian приблизительно тоже.
Поэтому рекомендую такую последовательность

```
sudo -s
apt-get update #это желательно, если хочется все новенькое
apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: После ввода 
sudo -s
Пишет
toki is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
toki - мое имя учетной записи.

Comment: Ну, так войди под root -ом! Либо sudo su, потом введи пароль

Comment: Это потому, что Вы не в списке привелигированных пользователей.
Решений два:
- стать таким пользователем. Если это Ваш личный комп - самое оптимальное. visudo и добавляемся
- использовать su - (да, su пробел и минус). Потом ввести пароль рута.

Comment: У меня пишет
visudo: команда не найдена

Comment: значит нужно установить. а это уже только от рута.
Предупреждаю сразу - visudo - это vim, поэтому нужно быть готовым:)

Comment: Тупанул немного. Все нормально заработало. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 5):

(**под root -ом**)

```
sudo su 
apt-get install make
apt-get install pidgin
```

Comment: можно перед этим всем выполнить еще aptitude update, а неизвестно как давно обновлялась система и каталоги

Comment: Да, это не повредит. Правда, если обсуждаемые программы не были ранее установлены, это не имеет значения. P.S. Не по теме немного, но если при установке пакетов debian их не устанваливает, ссылаясь на отсутствие каких-либо зависимых пакетов (в UBUNTU зависимые устанавливаются автоматом), то надо ввести sudo apt-get install -f и будет всем счастье :)

Answer (score 4):

Попробуй ввести в командной строке

```
sudo apt-get install make
```

Answer (score 2):

Сильно думаю, что можно поставить пакет от убунты.. не силен в debianских дистрибутивах, но думаю должно прокатить http://pidgin.im/download/ubuntu/